# The label in one cell doesn't show up in the tableView for iPhone

Tags: iphone, tableview, cell

I have a problem creating the `UITableView`, because I can't see in one of the cells the label and the stepper, that i assigned to it.

Here is the code, I hope someone can figure the problem out. When it arrives to case 4, it doesn't show the lblVarsta in the cell, only the stepper. I debugged it and the value is there, but the label with that value can't be seen. Thank you!

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UITextField *inputField;

lblRasa = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 12, 185, 30)];
lblCuloare = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 12, 185, 30)];
lblJudet = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 12, 185, 30)];
lbldate = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 12, 185, 30)];

inputField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 12, 185, 30)];
inputField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
inputField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
inputField.tag = indexPath.row;
inputField.delegate = self;


segmentedControl1 = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 10, 100, 10)];
segmentedControl2 = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 10, 100, 10)];

NSArray * segmentItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Da", @"Nu", nil];


 //    UIDatePicker *pv = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
 //    UIActionSheet *uas = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"pv" delegate:self      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Select", nil];
 //    
 //    [uas addSubview:pv];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

switch ([indexPath row])
{
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Nume";
        inputField.text = dog?dog.title:@"";
        [cell addSubview:inputField];
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Rasa";
        lblRasa.text = dog?dog.rasa:@"";
        [cell addSubview:lblRasa];
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Culoare";
        lblCuloare.text = dog?dog.culoare:@"";
        [cell addSubview:lblCuloare];
        break;
    case 3:{
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Data nasterii";
        lbldate.text = dog?dog.data_nas:@"";

        [cell addSubview:lbldate];
        [cell addSubview:actionSheet];
    break;}
    case 4:{
        lblVarsta = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 12, 185, 30)];
        stepper = [[UIStepper alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 10, 100, 10)];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Varsta";
        //inputField.text = dog?[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",dog.varsta]:@"";

        lblVarsta.text = @"3 ani";
       [stepper addTarget:self action:@selector(stepperValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


       [lblVarsta setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
       [lblVarsta setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        //[lbl5 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

        [stepper setStepValue:10];

        [cell addSubview:lblVarsta];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:stepper];
        break;}
    case 5:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Proprietar";
        inputField.text = dog?dog.proprietar:@"";
        [cell addSubview:inputField];
        break;
    case 6:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Judet";
        lblJudet.text = dog?dog.judet:@"";
        [cell addSubview:lblJudet];
        break;
    case 7:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Adresa";
        inputField.text = dog?dog.adresa:@"";
        [cell addSubview:inputField];
        break;
    case 8:{
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Parinti";
        //inputField.text = dog?dog.parinti:@"";
        //lblVarsta.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", stepper.value];

        segmentedControl1 = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems: segmentItems];
  //            segmentedControl1.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
  //            segmentedControl1.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

        [segmentedControl1 addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlIndexChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:segmentedControl1];
        break;}
    case 9:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Pedigree";
        segmentedControl1 = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems: segmentItems];
        [segmentedControl1 addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlIndexChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:segmentedControl2];
        break;
}

return cell;
 }
```

Comment: That is a bad `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation, after the cell is reused there will be already at least one added view, you'll need to reorganize the method to make the subviews hierarchy clear. As for the `case 4:`, you are using the white text color, that might be not visible on the default white background.

Comment: is the cell background color and the lblVarsta background color the same??

Comment: AppleDelegate and A-Live thank you both for your advices. A-Live can you please give me some hints, maybe a site or something, because I'm a beginner. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: might be your lbl fram size not set as  lblVarsta = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 12, 185, 30)];

Comment: What A-Live is referring to ...: The basic idea behind this is that cell objects can be re-used as soon as they become invisible. That simply saves memory resources. A table with 1000s entries only allocateds 8 cell objects if there are never more than 8 (or 7) being displayed at a time. Therfore when you create a new cell you will create all its relevant additional subviews and add them. You may hide and unhide the subviews case by case. However, you would not add 4 UITextLables (one for each case) just to name them differently in each case.

Comment: ...(cont)... in even more complex cases where the cells are significantly different from each other, you can use the cell identifier string to separate between diffrerent types of cells. But the basic principle remains the same. 1st try to reuse a cell of the same type. If the return value is nil then no cell can be reused. In that case a cell of the required type must be allocated and used.

Comment: Thank you Hermann Klecker. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
    [cell addSubview:lblVarsta];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:stepper];
```

and
        lblVarsta = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 12, 185, 30)];
        stepper = [[UIStepper alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 10, 100, 10)];

Why dont you try

```
     [cell.contentView addSubview:stepper];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:lblgarsta];
```

with the frames as follows

```
    lblVarsta = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 12, 100, 30)];
    stepper = [[UIStepper alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 10, 100, 10)];
```

You have to add both the subviews to the contentview and their frames have to be such that both of them can appear.

Comment: Srikanth thank you! Now I have another problem. I wrote it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238730/how-to-align-the-segmented-control-at-the-right-of-the-cell-of-the-tableview. Maybe you can figure this out too. Have a nice day!

Comment: I figured the problem out. I was redefining the object and lost the coordinates of the segmented Control.